# Keep checkstate of items in checkboxlist on search c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, search, checkedlistbox

So I'm working on a textbox based filter for a bunch of items in a Checked List Box in winforms using c#.

So far I have this code:

```
List<string> liscollection = new List<string>();
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) == false)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();

                foreach (string str in liscollection)
                {
                    if (str.Contains(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(str);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string str in liscollection)
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(str);
                }
            }
        }
```

It works fine, when I enter the text in TextBox1 all items not containing the entered text disappear.
The problem comes to the checked state on each item. Every time checkedListBox1.Items.Clear(); is called, the checked state also gets cleared.

Is there a method I could use to keep the filter working but to not clear the checked state of the items?

I have been looking for a while now and can't find anything on this and I am a beginner and can't come up with a solution on my own.

Thank you so much in advance for your time!

And excuse my English, it is not my first language :)

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, bool>` to track the status of each item in your collection.  Assuming your strings are unique.

Comment: Does an item that gets filtered out need to maintain it's checked state as well? For example, if the string `"Stack"` is in the `CheckedListBox` and it is checked, but it gets removed by the filter, should it remain checked if the filter changes and `"Stack"` is added back to the `CheckedListBox`?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson yes, that's precisely what i want to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`CheckListBox.Items`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items) is of type `ObjectCollection`, which means that it will accept any `object` and not just `string`. By default, `CheckedListBox` will display the results of `ToString` as the item's text.

What this means is that you could write a `class` to represent the items stored in the `CheckedListBox` that track their own `CheckedState` property, then override the `ToString` method so that it displays the text that you want.

```
// CheckedListBoxItem.cs
public class CheckedListBoxItem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The item's text - what will be displayed in the CheckedListBox.
    /// </summary>
    public string Text { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The item's check state.
    /// </summary>
    public CheckState CheckState { get; set; } = CheckState.Unchecked;

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether the item is checked or not.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Checked
    {
        get
        {
            return (CheckState == CheckState.Checked || CheckState == CheckState.Indeterminate);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
            }
            else
            {
                CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(string str, StringComparison comparison)
    {
        return Text.IndexOf(str, comparison) >= 0;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

The behavior of `CheckedListBoxItem.Checked` is based on [`CheckedListBox.GetItemChecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked) which treats `CheckState.Interetminate` as checked, and [`CheckedListBox.SetItemChecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked) which treats `true` as `CheckState.Checked` and `false` as `CheckState.Unchecked`.

In your `Form`, you would then change the type of `lstcollection` to `List<CheckedListBoxItem>` and set the `Text` property of each item to the string that you have now.

`CheckedListBox` doesn't have any way to bind the `CheckState` of each item, so you'll have to manage that yourself. Fortunately, there is the [`CheckedListBox.ItemChecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck) event that will fire whenever the checked state of an item changes. So, you can handle the event with a function like...

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    // Since each item in the CheckedListBox is of type CheckedListBoxItem, we can
    // just cast to that type...
    CheckedListBoxItem item = checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index] as CheckedListBoxItem;

    // Then set the checked state to the new value.
    item.CheckState = e.NewValue;
}
```

Your filter function remains largely unchanged, but when you're adding the items to the `CheckedListBox` you have to pass the `CheckedState` as well...

```
private List<CheckedListBoxItem> liscollection;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) == false)
    {
        foreach (var item in liscollection)
        {
            if (item.Contains(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item, item.CheckState);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in liscollection)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item, item.CheckState);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For a case like this, I wouldn't add the items to `checkedListBox1` at design time. I'd add them to `liscollection` at runtime, then add `liscollection` to `checkedListBox1.Items`.

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // You would add one item to liscollection for each item that you have in the checkedListBox1's designer and set the Text to whatever the item is now...
        liscollection = new List<CheckedListBoxItem>
        {
           new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = "The" },
           new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = "needs" },
           new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = "of" },
           new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = "the" },
           new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = "many" },
           new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = "outweigh" },
           new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = "the" },
           new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = "needs" },
           new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = "of" },
           new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = "the" },
           new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = "few" },
        };
        checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(liscollection.ToArray());
    }
}
```

If you really prefer to populate `checkedListBox1` from the designer, you can do that too. You just have to call `checkedListBox1.Items.Clear()` after populating `liscollection` and before calling `checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(...)`

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        liscollection = new List<CheckedListBoxItem>();
        foreach(string str in checkedListBox1.Items)
        {
            liscollection.Add(new CheckedListBoxItem { Text = str });
        }
        checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
        checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(liscollection.ToArray());
    }
}
```

The important line there is `checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(liscollection.ToArray())`. You want the `Items` to be instances of `CheckedListBoxItem`, that way in the `ItemCheck` event you can cast the item to an instance of `CheckedListBoxItem`. By populating `checkedListBox1` from the designer, you're populating it with `string`s only, so when you try to cast to a `CheckedListBoxItem` in the `ItemCheck` event it fails. That's why you're getting that `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for the answer and clear explanation! I tried following this and it makes a lot of sense, but unfortunately, whenever I try to check an item in the list box, i get the error "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on `item.CheckState = e.NewValue;`

Comment: Hi, @PereGil. Did you change the `liscollection` member to a `List<CheckListBoxItem>`? Or, is it still a `List<string>`? If it's still a `List<string>` then the cast will fail inside the `checkedListBox1_ItemCheck` event handler, and `item` will be null.

Comment: Hi! Yes, the `List<string>` I changed to `List<CheckListBoxItem>` I also re-read my question and forgot to mention that in my `Form` class I also had `liscollection.Clear();` and `foreach(string str in checkedListBox1.Items)
            {
                liscollection.Add(str);
            }` for the function to work. Not sure if maybe that has anything to do with your solution not working. And also now re-reading your answer maybe I skipped something in here "and set the Text property of each item to the string that you have now." ?

Comment: Where are you clearing `liscollection` and doing that `foreach (string str in checkedListBox1.Items)`? When filtering, or you're doing it one time when the `Form` loads to populate `liscollection`? Are you populating `checkedListBox1` in the designer, then in code iterating through it's `Items` to populate `liscollection`?

Comment: Precisely, I populated `checkedListBox1` in the designer, there iterating trhough `items` to populate the `liscollection` when loading the form (in `public Form1() {  }`

Comment: I just edited the answer. Hopefully that'll clear things up.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your time. The new code doesn't give the error anymore, and it filters the text like it did with my original code, but the items' check state is resetting again. Tried both ways, by still populating the checklistbox in the designer and by adding them at runtime.

Comment: If you're still calling `liscollection.Clear` anywhere, then remove it. You shouldn't have to clear `liscollection` at all once it's been populated.

Comment: hmm... I never called `liscollection.Clear` , I call `checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();` before comparing the `textBox1.Text`, if I remove that the function will not work, it will instead duplicate the matches each time I type something

Comment: At this point, I think the best thing to do would be to create a new question with your code as it is now. It is working for me, so without being able to see the code I'd just be guessing at what the problem might be.

Comment: I just tried what I have now in a new project and it works perfectly. There's nothing different that I can see, but maybe I was missing something... Anyway, thank you SO MUCH for your time and especially for explaining everything to me, I learned a lot and it finally worked! :)